# PHP - Get URL Parameters and Rearrange In Array

Tags: php, arrays, url, url-routing, url-parameters

The URL coming to the page looks something like this:

"http://localhost/testSite/id/1/friend_id/32/msg_id/5/category_id/40"

I would like to strip these variables (**id/1**, **friend_id/32**, **msg_id/5** etc.) and make them into an array like this:

```
$params = array('id' => 1, 'friend_id' => 32, 'msg_id' => 5, 'category_id' => 40)
```

So that I can access these values like this:

```
$params['id']; $params['friend_id'];
```

I thought I was getting somewhere with the following code, but it isn't much help.

```
    $keys = explode('/', $url);
    $k2 = $keys;
    $result = array();

    foreach ($keys as $k => $v) {
       $result[$v] = next($k2); 
    }
    array_pop($result);
    print_r($result);
```

I would get the following output from the code above:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [1] => friend_id
    [friend_id] => 32
    [32] => msg_id
    [msg_id] => 5
    [5] => category_id
    [category_id] => 40
)
```

Has anyone done this previously? How can I modify the code above to make it work properly? Or does anyone have some other ideas on how to do this?

I would really appreciate any help,
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using uri parameters? ie: `http://localhost/testSite?id=1&friend_id=32&msg_id=5&category_id=40`  This the array is just in `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`

Comment: @cegfault No, there isn't any particular reason. I'm just experimenting with mod_rewrite and PHP.

Comment: If you wanted to do this at the HTTPD level, in .htaccess instead of rewriting the url, you could leave it intact and load the pieces into an Apache environment variable (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html) which will be available in the $_SERVER (http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) superglobal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is done by a framework there should be way to get the parameters. See the doc in that case.

Otherwise you can use simple regex to parse it. The idea is to use define a prefix (`$root` in the code).

```
$url = 'http://localhost/testSite/id/1/friend_id/32/msg_id/5/category_id/40';
$root = 'http://localhost/testSite/';
$params =  substr($url, strlen($root));
preg_match_all("#([^/]+)/([^/]+)#", $params, $match);
$result = array_combine($match[1], $match[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$parts = explode('/', $url);
$len = count($parts);
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i+=2) {
  $result[$parts[$i]] = $parts[$i+1];
}
```